# Convert SQL Query with Subquery to Laravel query

Tags: sql, laravel, subquery

Is it possible to convert my SQL Query to Laravel 4 Query

SQL:

```
SELECT
  Branch_tbl.ID,
  Branch_tbl.BranchName,
  (
    SELECT
      SUM(Expenses.Expense)
    FROM
      Expenses
    WHERE
     Expenses.BranchID = Branch_tbl.ID 
  ) as 'Total Expenses'
FROM
  Branch_tbl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try raw expression (maybe it's not to best solution)

```
DB::table('branch_tbl')
->select(
  'branch_tbl.id',
  'branch_tbl.branchname',
  DB::raw("
  ( select sum(expenses.expense) from expenses where
    expenses.branchid = branch_tbl.id 
  )as 'total expenses'"))->get();
```

If you have a complex subquery you can separate it:

```
$subQuery = DB::table('expenses')
        ->select(DB::raw('sum(expenses.expense)'))
        ->whereRaw('expenses.branchid = branch_tbl.id');

DB::table('branch_tbl')
->select('branch_tbl.id','branch_tbl.branchname',
    DB::raw("(" . $subQuery->toSql() . ") as 'total expenses'")
)
->get();
```

Be careful not to create any SQL injection with raw expression.