# how to convert my MySql query in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

i am little bit confused that how my query convert in laravel..

```
select users.username,users.photo, questions.*,
(Select count(*) from answers 
 where answers.q_id=questions.id) as aAccount from questions
 INNER JOIN users ON users.id=questions.user_id
```

Comment: use raw query method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23826949/convert-sql-query-with-subquery-to-laravel-query. This may help & yeah use raw query as @JYoThI suggested

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries use Laravel's query builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Raw query**

These expressions will be injected into the query as strings, so be careful not to create any SQL injection points! To create a raw expression, you may use the DB::raw method

```
    DB::table('questions')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'questions.user_id')
    ->select('users.username','users.photo', 'questions.*',
    DB::raw("
    (   Select count(*) from answers 
        where answers.q_id=questions.id
    )as 'aAccount'")
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted JYoThl answer as it's exactly how I'd breakdown this query into eloquent, though in instances where a portion of your Eloquent query becomes raw, I personally prefer keeping the entire sql raw.  You can still inject variables into it if required.

In my experience, the amount of time spent normalizing a more complex query like this will be used when you go back to the code to re-read it.

Here's how you would pass your sql in it's raw format. I also like to convert the array into a collection, as collections offer a variety of methods.  Hope this helps!

```
$questions = collect(DB::select( DB::raw("
    select users.username,users.photo, questions.*, 
(Select count(*) from answers where answers.q_id=questions.id) as aAccount 
            from questions
                INNER JOIN users ON users.id=questions.user_id")
    ));
```

You would add variables into an array() area if you want to inject a variable.  If you wanted to do that you would do something like this:

```
DB::select( DB::raw("select * from user where user = :user"), array('user' => $user))
```